# CoInitialize required in MFC app on XP but not Vista/Win7?

Tags: web-services, windows-7, com, mfc, windows-xp

I have written a SOAP Web Service that I'm trying to consume from an MFC application. The MFC application was not generated with ActiveX control support or Automation. When I run the MFC application from Vista or Win7, there's no problem accessing the Web Service. When I run the MFC application from XP (SP3), the Web Service call fails with `0x800401F0` `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` "CoInitialize has not been called". Calling `CoInitialize(NULL)` fixes the XP problem.

Why is the MFC app in XP behaving differently than Vista/Win7 in this case?

**EDIT2: Auto-generated web service access code added**

net_webservicexwww.h

```
//
// sproxy.exe generated file
// do not modify this file
//
// Created: 08/15/2013@13:09:29
//

#pragma once


#if !defined(_WIN32_WINDOWS) && !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && !defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#pragma message("warning: defining _WIN32_WINDOWS = 0x0410")
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410
#endif

#include <atlsoap.h>

namespace USZip
{

template <typename TClient = CSoapSocketClientT<> >
class CUSZipT : 
    public TClient, 
    public CSoapRootHandler
{
protected:

    const _soapmap ** GetFunctionMap();
    const _soapmap ** GetHeaderMap();
    void * GetHeaderValue();
    const wchar_t * GetNamespaceUri();
    const char * GetServiceName();
    const char * GetNamespaceUriA();
    HRESULT CallFunction(
        void *pvParam, 
        const wchar_t *wszLocalName, int cchLocalName,
        size_t nItem);
    HRESULT GetClientReader(ISAXXMLReader **ppReader);

public:

    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
    {
        if (ppv == NULL)
        {
            return E_POINTER;
        }

        *ppv = NULL;

        if (InlineIsEqualGUID(riid, IID_IUnknown) ||
            InlineIsEqualGUID(riid, IID_ISAXContentHandler))
        {
            *ppv = static_cast<ISAXContentHandler *>(this);
            return S_OK;
        }

        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    ULONG __stdcall AddRef()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    ULONG __stdcall Release()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    CUSZipT(ISAXXMLReader *pReader = NULL)
        :TClient(_T("http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx"))
    {
        SetClient(true);
        SetReader(pReader);
    }

    ~CUSZipT()
    {
        Uninitialize();
    }

    void Uninitialize()
    {
        UninitializeSOAP();
    }   

    HRESULT GetInfoByAreaCode(
        BSTR USAreaCode, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByAreaCodeResult
    );

    HRESULT GetInfoByCity(
        BSTR USCity, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByCityResult
    );

    HRESULT GetInfoByState(
        BSTR USState, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByStateResult
    );

    HRESULT GetInfoByZIP(
        BSTR USZip, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByZIPResult
    );
};

typedef CUSZipT<> CUSZip;

struct __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_struct
{
    BSTR USAreaCode;
    BSTR GetInfoByAreaCodeResult;
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_entries[] =
{

    {
        0x529BE19C, 
        "USAreaCode", 
        L"USAreaCode", 
        sizeof("USAreaCode")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_IN | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_struct, USAreaCode),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    {
        0xCB1A9C5A, 
        "GetInfoByAreaCodeResult", 
        L"GetInfoByAreaCodeResult", 
        sizeof("GetInfoByAreaCodeResult")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_OUT | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_struct, GetInfoByAreaCodeResult),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    { 0x00000000 }
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_map =
{
    0xFBDA3B2A,
    "GetInfoByAreaCode",
    L"GetInfoByAreaCodeResponse",
    sizeof("GetInfoByAreaCode")-1,
    sizeof("GetInfoByAreaCodeResponse")-1,
    SOAPMAP_FUNC,
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_entries,
    sizeof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_struct),
    1,
    -1,
    SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
    0x8833C2E7,
    "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
};


struct __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_struct
{
    BSTR USCity;
    BSTR GetInfoByCityResult;
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_entries[] =
{

    {
        0xCC4AFAC1, 
        "USCity", 
        L"USCity", 
        sizeof("USCity")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_IN | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_struct, USCity),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    {
        0xE3D245BF, 
        "GetInfoByCityResult", 
        L"GetInfoByCityResult", 
        sizeof("GetInfoByCityResult")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_OUT | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_struct, GetInfoByCityResult),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    { 0x00000000 }
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_map =
{
    0x2121D1CF,
    "GetInfoByCity",
    L"GetInfoByCityResponse",
    sizeof("GetInfoByCity")-1,
    sizeof("GetInfoByCityResponse")-1,
    SOAPMAP_FUNC,
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_entries,
    sizeof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_struct),
    1,
    -1,
    SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
    0x8833C2E7,
    "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
};


struct __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_struct
{
    BSTR USState;
    BSTR GetInfoByStateResult;
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_entries[] =
{

    {
        0x56D19209, 
        "USState", 
        L"USState", 
        sizeof("USState")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_IN | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByState_struct, USState),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    {
        0x271736E7, 
        "GetInfoByStateResult", 
        L"GetInfoByStateResult", 
        sizeof("GetInfoByStateResult")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_OUT | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByState_struct, GetInfoByStateResult),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    { 0x00000000 }
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_map =
{
    0x4967ACF7,
    "GetInfoByState",
    L"GetInfoByStateResponse",
    sizeof("GetInfoByState")-1,
    sizeof("GetInfoByStateResponse")-1,
    SOAPMAP_FUNC,
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_entries,
    sizeof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByState_struct),
    1,
    -1,
    SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
    0x8833C2E7,
    "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
};


struct __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_struct
{
    BSTR USZip;
    BSTR GetInfoByZIPResult;
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_entries[] =
{

    {
        0x0631331B, 
        "USZip", 
        L"USZip", 
        sizeof("USZip")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_IN | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_struct, USZip),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    {
        0xD0D29D79, 
        "GetInfoByZIPResult", 
        L"GetInfoByZIPResult", 
        sizeof("GetInfoByZIPResult")-1, 
        SOAPTYPE_STRING, 
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_OUT | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL | SOAPFLAG_NULLABLE,
        offsetof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_struct, GetInfoByZIPResult),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        -1,
    },
    { 0x00000000 }
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_map =
{
    0x4F970009,
    "GetInfoByZIP",
    L"GetInfoByZIPResponse",
    sizeof("GetInfoByZIP")-1,
    sizeof("GetInfoByZIPResponse")-1,
    SOAPMAP_FUNC,
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_entries,
    sizeof(__CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_struct),
    1,
    -1,
    SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
    0x8833C2E7,
    "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
    sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
};

extern __declspec(selectany) const _soapmap * __CUSZip_funcs[] =
{
    &__CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_map,
    &__CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_map,
    &__CUSZip_GetInfoByState_map,
    &__CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_map,
    NULL
};

template <typename TClient>
inline HRESULT CUSZipT<TClient>::GetInfoByAreaCode(
        BSTR USAreaCode, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByAreaCodeResult
    )
{
    if ( GetInfoByAreaCodeResult == NULL )
        return E_POINTER;

    HRESULT __atlsoap_hr = InitializeSOAP(NULL);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_INITIALIZE_ERROR);
        return __atlsoap_hr;
    }

    CleanupClient();

    CComPtr<IStream> __atlsoap_spReadStream;
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_struct __params;
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    __params.USAreaCode = USAreaCode;

    __atlsoap_hr = SetClientStruct(&__params, 0);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_OUTOFMEMORY);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = GenerateResponse(GetWriteStream());
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_GENERATE_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = SendRequest(_T("SOAPAction: \"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByAreaCode\"\r\n"));
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }
    __atlsoap_hr = GetReadStream(&__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_READ_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    // cleanup any in/out-params and out-headers from previous calls
    Cleanup();
    __atlsoap_hr = BeginParse(__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_PARSE_ERROR);
        goto __cleanup;
    }

    *GetInfoByAreaCodeResult = __params.GetInfoByAreaCodeResult;
    goto __skip_cleanup;

__cleanup:
    Cleanup();
__skip_cleanup:
    ResetClientState(true);
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    return __atlsoap_hr;
}

template <typename TClient>
inline HRESULT CUSZipT<TClient>::GetInfoByCity(
        BSTR USCity, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByCityResult
    )
{
    if ( GetInfoByCityResult == NULL )
        return E_POINTER;

    HRESULT __atlsoap_hr = InitializeSOAP(NULL);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_INITIALIZE_ERROR);
        return __atlsoap_hr;
    }

    CleanupClient();

    CComPtr<IStream> __atlsoap_spReadStream;
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_struct __params;
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    __params.USCity = USCity;

    __atlsoap_hr = SetClientStruct(&__params, 1);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_OUTOFMEMORY);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = GenerateResponse(GetWriteStream());
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_GENERATE_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = SendRequest(_T("SOAPAction: \"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByCity\"\r\n"));
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }
    __atlsoap_hr = GetReadStream(&__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_READ_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    // cleanup any in/out-params and out-headers from previous calls
    Cleanup();
    __atlsoap_hr = BeginParse(__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_PARSE_ERROR);
        goto __cleanup;
    }

    *GetInfoByCityResult = __params.GetInfoByCityResult;
    goto __skip_cleanup;

__cleanup:
    Cleanup();
__skip_cleanup:
    ResetClientState(true);
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    return __atlsoap_hr;
}

template <typename TClient>
inline HRESULT CUSZipT<TClient>::GetInfoByState(
        BSTR USState, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByStateResult
    )
{
    if ( GetInfoByStateResult == NULL )
        return E_POINTER;

    HRESULT __atlsoap_hr = InitializeSOAP(NULL);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_INITIALIZE_ERROR);
        return __atlsoap_hr;
    }

    CleanupClient();

    CComPtr<IStream> __atlsoap_spReadStream;
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_struct __params;
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    __params.USState = USState;

    __atlsoap_hr = SetClientStruct(&__params, 2);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_OUTOFMEMORY);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = GenerateResponse(GetWriteStream());
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_GENERATE_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = SendRequest(_T("SOAPAction: \"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByState\"\r\n"));
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }
    __atlsoap_hr = GetReadStream(&__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_READ_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    // cleanup any in/out-params and out-headers from previous calls
    Cleanup();
    __atlsoap_hr = BeginParse(__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_PARSE_ERROR);
        goto __cleanup;
    }

    *GetInfoByStateResult = __params.GetInfoByStateResult;
    goto __skip_cleanup;

__cleanup:
    Cleanup();
__skip_cleanup:
    ResetClientState(true);
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    return __atlsoap_hr;
}

template <typename TClient>
inline HRESULT CUSZipT<TClient>::GetInfoByZIP(
        BSTR USZip, 
        BSTR* GetInfoByZIPResult
    )
{
    if ( GetInfoByZIPResult == NULL )
        return E_POINTER;

    HRESULT __atlsoap_hr = InitializeSOAP(NULL);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_INITIALIZE_ERROR);
        return __atlsoap_hr;
    }

    CleanupClient();

    CComPtr<IStream> __atlsoap_spReadStream;
    __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_struct __params;
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    __params.USZip = USZip;

    __atlsoap_hr = SetClientStruct(&__params, 3);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_OUTOFMEMORY);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = GenerateResponse(GetWriteStream());
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_GENERATE_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    __atlsoap_hr = SendRequest(_T("SOAPAction: \"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByZIP\"\r\n"));
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }
    __atlsoap_hr = GetReadStream(&__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_READ_ERROR);
        goto __skip_cleanup;
    }

    // cleanup any in/out-params and out-headers from previous calls
    Cleanup();
    __atlsoap_hr = BeginParse(__atlsoap_spReadStream);
    if (FAILED(__atlsoap_hr))
    {
        SetClientError(SOAPCLIENT_PARSE_ERROR);
        goto __cleanup;
    }

    *GetInfoByZIPResult = __params.GetInfoByZIPResult;
    goto __skip_cleanup;

__cleanup:
    Cleanup();
__skip_cleanup:
    ResetClientState(true);
    memset(&__params, 0x00, sizeof(__params));
    return __atlsoap_hr;
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline const _soapmap ** CUSZipT<TClient>::GetFunctionMap()
{
    return __CUSZip_funcs;
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline const _soapmap ** CUSZipT<TClient>::GetHeaderMap()
{
    static const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_atlsoapheader_entries[] =
    {
        { 0x00000000 }
    };

    static const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_atlsoapheader_map = 
    {
        0xFBDA3B2A,
        "GetInfoByAreaCode",
        L"GetInfoByAreaCodeResponse",
        sizeof("GetInfoByAreaCode")-1,
        sizeof("GetInfoByAreaCodeResponse")-1,
        SOAPMAP_HEADER,
        __CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_atlsoapheader_entries,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
        0x8833C2E7,
        "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
    };

    static const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_atlsoapheader_entries[] =
    {
        { 0x00000000 }
    };

    static const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_atlsoapheader_map = 
    {
        0x2121D1CF,
        "GetInfoByCity",
        L"GetInfoByCityResponse",
        sizeof("GetInfoByCity")-1,
        sizeof("GetInfoByCityResponse")-1,
        SOAPMAP_HEADER,
        __CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_atlsoapheader_entries,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
        0x8833C2E7,
        "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
    };

    static const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_atlsoapheader_entries[] =
    {
        { 0x00000000 }
    };

    static const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_atlsoapheader_map = 
    {
        0x4967ACF7,
        "GetInfoByState",
        L"GetInfoByStateResponse",
        sizeof("GetInfoByState")-1,
        sizeof("GetInfoByStateResponse")-1,
        SOAPMAP_HEADER,
        __CUSZip_GetInfoByState_atlsoapheader_entries,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
        0x8833C2E7,
        "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
    };

    static const _soapmapentry __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_atlsoapheader_entries[] =
    {
        { 0x00000000 }
    };

    static const _soapmap __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_atlsoapheader_map = 
    {
        0x4F970009,
        "GetInfoByZIP",
        L"GetInfoByZIPResponse",
        sizeof("GetInfoByZIP")-1,
        sizeof("GetInfoByZIPResponse")-1,
        SOAPMAP_HEADER,
        __CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_atlsoapheader_entries,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        SOAPFLAG_NONE | SOAPFLAG_PID | SOAPFLAG_DOCUMENT | SOAPFLAG_LITERAL,
        0x8833C2E7,
        "http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        L"http://www.webserviceX.NET",
        sizeof("http://www.webserviceX.NET")-1
    };


    static const _soapmap * __CUSZip_headers[] =
    {
        &__CUSZip_GetInfoByAreaCode_atlsoapheader_map,
        &__CUSZip_GetInfoByCity_atlsoapheader_map,
        &__CUSZip_GetInfoByState_atlsoapheader_map,
        &__CUSZip_GetInfoByZIP_atlsoapheader_map,
        NULL
    };

    return __CUSZip_headers;
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline void * CUSZipT<TClient>::GetHeaderValue()
{
    return this;
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline const wchar_t * CUSZipT<TClient>::GetNamespaceUri()
{
    return L"http://www.webserviceX.NET";
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline const char * CUSZipT<TClient>::GetServiceName()
{
    return NULL;
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline const char * CUSZipT<TClient>::GetNamespaceUriA()
{
    return "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline HRESULT CUSZipT<TClient>::CallFunction(
    void *, 
    const wchar_t *, int,
    size_t)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

template <typename TClient>
ATL_NOINLINE inline HRESULT CUSZipT<TClient>::GetClientReader(ISAXXMLReader **ppReader)
{
    if (ppReader == NULL)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    CComPtr<ISAXXMLReader> spReader = GetReader();
    if (spReader.p != NULL)
    {
        *ppReader = spReader.Detach();
        return S_OK;
    }
    return TClient::GetClientReader(ppReader);
}

} // namespace USZip
```

**EDIT: Source code added.**

MFC Application created from VS2005 "MFC Application" template. All default wizard values except chose "Dialog based" Application Type and unchecked "ActiveX controls" from the Advanced features wizard settings.

The Web Service call in the code below (OnBnClickedCallWebWervice) works when run from Vista and Win7 systems. When run from an XP system, the call fails with `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` as the HRESULT. If I add `CoInitialize(NULL)` to the InitInstance method, the Web Service call works on all three platforms.

TestApp.cpp

```
// TestApp.cpp : Defines the class behaviors for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestApp.h"
#include "TestAppDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CTestAppApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestAppApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestAppApp construction

CTestAppApp::CTestAppApp()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only CTestAppApp object

CTestAppApp theApp;


// CTestAppApp initialization

BOOL CTestAppApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    // of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    // the specific initialization routines you do not need
    // Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
    // TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
    // such as the name of your company or organization
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

    CTestAppDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}
```

TestAppDlg.cpp

```
// TestAppDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestApp.h"
#include "TestAppDlg.h"
#include "WebService.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestAppDlg dialog




CTestAppDlg::CTestAppDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CTestAppDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CTestAppDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestAppDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_CALLWEBSERVICE, &CTestAppDlg::OnBnClickedCallWebWervice)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CTestAppDlg message handlers

BOOL CTestAppDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CTestAppDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CTestAppDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CTestAppDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CTestAppDlg::OnBnClickedCallWebWervice()
{
    USZip::CUSZip* c = new USZip::CUSZip();

    BSTR bstrResult;
    HRESULT hr = c->GetInfoByZIP(CComBSTR(_T("90814")), &bstrResult);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CString csResult(bstrResult);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_MSG)->SetWindowText(csResult);
    }
    else
    {
        CString csResult;
        csResult.Format(_T("Call to web service failed with HRESULT=0x%0x"), hr);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_MSG)->SetWindowText(csResult);
    }

    delete c;
}
```

Comment: You don't show any code, so the typical reasons: `1` something else initializes COM on the threads in question. `2` [Implicit MTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147048/why-i-dont-need-call-coinitialize-in-a-thread-created-inside-a-com-thread/18148750#18148750) applies to the uninitialized threads and things are rolling well working the issue around.

Comment: It's almost a bare-bones dialog based MFC app with one button that calls a very simple Web Service. The Web Service reference was added to the Visual Studio 2005 project via "Add Web Reference..." from the project. That's it. It behaves differently on XP than it does running on Vista/Win7 with no code changes, so your point (1) doesn't seem to apply. I'm not sure if your item (2) explanation applies as well -- this is a simple single-threaded Win32 MFC project.

Comment: We're guessing - you can check it. Do `CoInitialize` in Vista/7 and check result to see if the thread is already COM-initialized (returned values is `S_FALSE`). The second item... again if you can check it with debugger - you can see the details, you can see if other threads exist.

Comment: Ok, I debugged as you suggested and CoInitialize running in Win7 returns S_OK. There is only the main thread until the Web Service call is made, at which point, 4 more "Win32 Thread"s are spawned.

Comment: Code snippets are irrelevant. The problem is obviously inside `USZip::CUSZip::GetInfoByZIP`, which code is not shown.

Comment: Yes, Roman, you are correct. However, the GetInfoByZIP code is auto-generated by Visual Studio 2005 after performing the "Add Web Reference..." step. I'll add that code to the original post. My frustration is that this should be a very common problem because the code is auto-generated -- I'm surprised there isn't more information or knowledge about this problem.